# Odd one out questions

Tags: contest-math, puzzle

These are two questions given to a grade 5 student.
I couldn't get a conclusive and compelling answer to any. 
[image: enge]

[image: ee]

Comment: In both sets, d) represents the set with a different set of digits compared with the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In 38**:
  I would say b) for the only reason that it is the only value that could (should) be written in a shorter form: 1.1 instead of 1.10.

**In 5**
c) is the only one using 4 digits, not 2. Also, it uses the only even digit(4).

Comment: Your reasoning for 38 is good, but I disagree with that for 5 since d) has a similar condition...  Except that bit about the even digit.

Comment: 91, 119: 2 digits.

Comment: Ah, got it, good point

Comment: interesting observation.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is one.  I have seen one like 38 where three of the four choices had a clear difference from all the rest, so you were supposed to pick the fourth.  I would not call that grade 5 logic-it was in a Martin Gardner column.  But here I can find something wrong with all the choices-1.01 is the only one with a zero in the middle, 1.10 is the only one that ends in 0, 1.11 is the only one with an odd number of 1's, 1.111 is the only one with four digits.

Comment: agreed,nothing conclusive.Also 1.10 is the only one with a redundant digit(the zero).

Comment: @Ross I have first downvoted your answer, because it looked as one of those that try to "outsmart" the author, without taking into account that it is a 5th grade problem, but since there are several others in the same direction, decided to remove my vote, but for some reason it does not let me now... Hopefully, this does not matter that much for you.

Comment: @Vadim:  no problem.  I believe it is not appropriate for 5th grade.   In fact, I don't think it is a good problem at all.  To make it a good problem, when somebody explains the answer you should be convinced.  Maybe there is a good answer, but nobody has shown it yet.

Comment: @RossMillikan I agree, and the OP already says that he/she cannot find a compelling answer, I just thought that there might be a 10-year boy/girl sitting with their farther/mother trying to get some ideas about how to solve this, and simply criticizing the problem itself (and implicitly their teacher) is not the best thing to do, even if the teacher is mistaken this time giving this problem. So, anyway, let move on.

Comment: $1.01$ is the only option with a value less than $1.1$. (Of course, this isn't really *too* much better than punting with "item $x$ is the only option with value equal to item $x$".)

Answer (score 4):

I would say c) and b) for the two problems.  For the first one, 1.11 is the only number that's written with an odd number of 1's (making it literally the odd one out).  For the second, the pair (7,9) is the only one which, when written in binary, uses an *even* number of 0's.  I.e., (3,5)=(11,101) has one 0, (7,9)=(111,1001) has two, (41,53)=(101001,110101) has five, and (91,119)=(1011011,1110111) has three.

On the other hand, c) is a compelling answer for the second problem because it's the only one that involves an even digit.

On yet one more hand, d) is a compelling answer because (91,119) is the only pair that's not relatively prime.

Clearly this makes a) the compelling answer, because it's the only one for which I'm unable to find anything compelling that makes it stand out from the others....

Answer (score 3):

In $38$, if you consider those to be numbers in base two expansion, $d$) is the only one that is not a multiple of $.25$ once converted to base $10$.

In $5$, $c$ is the only one that is not a pair of numbers, with one congruent to $1$, the other congruent to $3$ mod $4$.

We can keep naming ways to find one that is the "odd one out"... it's quite subjective.

Comment: OK, changing my comment: 9 was removed.